# Trouble understanding maximum likelihood estimators

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Consider a scenario in which an individual flips ten coins, and obtains the following result: $$\{HHHTTHHTHH\}$$

The probability for such a result to occur is given by, $$\pi^7(1-\pi)^3,$$ where $\pi$ is the probability of flipping heads. We can estimate $\pi$ using maximum likelihood estimation. We have that $$\frac{d\Pr}{d\pi}=7\pi^6(1-\pi)^3-3\pi^7(1-\pi)^2=\pi^6(1-\pi)^2(7-10\pi)=0.$$ Maximizing the probability we find our parameter to be $\pi=0.7$ (as one would expect). I understand that one can proceed similarly for a continuous distribution, such as the normal distribution (but with two parameters in the case of a normal distribution). However, I'm having some trouble finding examples of how to proceed in the case of a continuous probability density function. Examples would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps try finding the MLE of the rate $\lambda$ based on a random sample of size $n$ from an exponential distribution. Google 'exponential distribution', choose Wikipedia, and go to parameter estimation.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on the suggestion made by BruceET in a comment: Let $T_1,\ldots,T_n$ be i.i.d. from the exponential distribution
$$
e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda\,dt) \quad \text{for } t\ge0.
$$
Thus we have $\Pr(T_1>t) = e^{-\lambda t}$ for $t\ge0.$

Then the likelihood is
$$
L(\lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^n (\lambda e^{-\lambda t_i}) = \lambda^n e^{-\lambda\sum_{i=1}^n t_i}
$$
and then
$$
\ell(\lambda) = \log L(\lambda) = n\log\lambda - \lambda\sum_{i=1}^n t_i,
$$
so that
$$
\ell\,'(\lambda) = \frac n \lambda - \sum_{i=1}^n t_i\quad  \begin{cases} \ge0 & \text{if } 0\le\lambda\le \dfrac n {\sum_{i=1}^n t_i}, \\[8pt]  \le0& \text{if } \phantom{0 \le {}} \lambda \ge \dfrac n {\sum_{i=1}^n t_i}. \end{cases}
$$